# Repeat last sbt command?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Is there a short sbt command or keyboard-shortcut to re-invoke the last command issued? I am finding myself with the situation of having to execute this repeatedly:

```
> test-only my.long.package.etc.class.name
```

And copy+pasting is kind of annoying. I am using the sbt console from within IntelliJ IDEA, so cursor-up to scroll through the history doesn't work.

Comment: The latest version of the sbt plugin does have arrow-up for history. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/simple-build-tool/SSt47q8EaOI

Comment: @Luigi - thanks, I had down-graded to 1.3 because I couldn't stand the new vertical split line moving around, and I had issues with the scrollbar. I have found work-arounds, though, so I'm willing to go back to 1.4. So if you post that as an answer, I will accept. On the other hand, there is a very simple solution which is `~test-only my.long.package.etc.class.name` which will re-run the test after I make adjustments and save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version 1.4.0 of the sbt plug-in for IDEA, since this has support for arrow-key history.

Answer (score 12):

You want `!!`. To see the help for `sbt`, type `help` at the prompt:

```
> help

  help                         Displays this help message or prints detailed help on requested commands (run 'help <command>').
  about                        Displays basic information about sbt and the build.
  reload                       (Re)loads the project in the current directory
  settings                     Lists the settings defined for the current project.
  tasks                        Lists the tasks defined for the current project.
  projects                     Lists the names of available projects or temporarily adds/removes extra builds to the session.
  project                      Displays the current project or changes to the provided `project`.
  set                          Evaluates a Setting and applies it to the current project.
  session                      Manipulates session settings.  For details, run 'help session'.
  inspect                      Prints the value for 'key', the defining scope, delegates, related definitions, and dependencies.
  ; <command> (; <command>)*   Runs the provided semicolon-separated commands.
  ~ <command>                  Executes the specified command whenever source files change.
  last                         Displays output from a previous command or the output from a specific task.
  last-grep                    Shows lines from the last output for 'key' that match 'pattern'.
  exit                         Terminates the build.
  show <key>                   Displays the result of evaluating the setting or task associated with 'key'.

More command help available using 'help <command>' for:
  !, -, <, alias, append, apply, eval, iflast, reboot, shell
```

and then to get help on `!`:

```
> !
History commands:
   !!    Execute the last command again
   !:    Show all previous commands
   !:n    Show the last n commands
   !n    Execute the command with index n, as shown by the !: command
   !-n    Execute the nth command before this one
   !string    Execute the most recent command starting with 'string'
   !?string    Execute the most recent command containing 'string'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `!x` history commands don't work correctly in the IDEA plugin; something to do with JLine

Comment: Ah ok, I tried `help !` which did give me anything. Unfortunately as @LuigiPlinge pointed out, you only get `[error] Invalid history index: X` in IDEA.

Comment: History could be implemented without JLine so that it works in IDEA.  A pull request implementing this would be welcome.  (There might already be a bug for this for the IDEA plugin, so you might also look there.)

Comment: For an immediate workaround, you might also see `help alias`.

Comment: @MarkHarrah - `alias` is interesting. is it possible to define aliases in a `build.sbt` by any chance?

Comment: In 0.12.0 and later, yes.  See https://groups.google.com/d/topic/simple-build-tool/jN5_NYfUUPo/discussion for that and options for 0.11.x.